# Join all record even not match

Tags: sql

I have tables_1 and table_2

table_1

```
id   name   cost
100  joe     10
101  bob     20
102  mary    30
```

table_2

```
id   name
100  joe 
101  bob
102  mary
103  tom
```

I want to join these tables even no match id and expect result

```
id   name   cost
100  joe    10
101  bob    20
102  mary   30
103  tom    null
```

My query

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.column1, t1.column2
from Table_1 t1
join Table_1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
and  t1.id <> t2.id
```

I got nothing return. Need some help. Thank you

Comment: `t1.id = t2.id and  t1.id <> t2.id` will always be false

Comment: I just guess, but anyway to fix this. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `right join` (or a `left join` if you reverse the order of tables in the join)

```
select table_2.id, table_2.name, table_1.cost
from table_1 right join table_2
on table_1.id = table_2.id
```

Comment: but I want all return records from table1  along with tom

Comment: @qphan yes, the code does what you want, you can try it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73cb05ce0a30063b708e65bc3b34fca3

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's working. TY so much

Comment: I'm back for quick question. I used CTE but ID 104 for Tom not come out.
with cte1 as
(select * from Table_1)
,

cte2 as
(select * from Table_2)

,
ctejoin as
(
select t2.id, t2.name, t1.cost
from cte1 t1
left join cte2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
)
select * from ctejoin

Comment: @qphan either change it to a `right join` or flip the order of the tables in the `join` clause.

Comment: You're correct, change to RIGHT JOIN. But I don't understand that between no cte and cte. Again thank you.

Comment: @qphan no difference! You have cte1 join cte2. cte2 is the one on the *right* of the join keyword, and the missing row is from cte2, therefore you need a *right* join. Exactly the same when no cte.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a simple *outer join*

```
select t2.id, t2.name, t1.cost
from table_2 t2
left join table_1 t1 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: Appears you have accepted the other answer, which is also perfectly correct, although I tend to find using right-outer joins unintuitive, prefering to construct the query in a left-to-right fashion.